# History of Linux kernel development question, what's next?

Tags: discussion

So we've reopened this question - [Git, Linux kernel and ticketing/bug-reporting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163639/git-linux-kernel-and-ticketing-bug-reporting) - and I'd like to help it get as thorough an answer as possible. I've been adding links to resources that I'd like to get incorporated into the eventual answer, but I feel that among the community that I'm aware of, that we're just ill equipped to do it justice.

So I'm asking within our ranks if anyone of us knows personally any of the actual developers that are at least a lieutenant to Linus or a level below? I feel without one of these people's input, this question is going to languish and not get as solid an answer as it could possibly.

These types of questions are important from a nostalgia & morale point of view to our community, and the broader Linux community; as well as showing how something as complicated as the Linux kernel can be developed by such a broad community of developers, and for so long a period of time.

So who knows any one that can help us to knock this question's answer out?

**NOTE:** I'd be willing to make a sizable bounty payment to get a high ranking person to help capture this important information for our site!

Comment: I added a comment to the Q re, usenet probably being one place to start looking for clues about this.  Someone has a record of everything ever done on usenet somewhere don't they?  At some point linux must have become a topic of conversation there and around the same time people probably found bugs to report.

Comment: I really liked this idea so I emailed Linus. His reply: *\*\*\*k off already!* That's a good sign, right?

Comment: I actually reached out to him via G+ to see if he'd be willing. Haven't heard anything back as of yet. We discussed this the other day in the chatroom if you're curious what I wrote him. Starts here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18325398#18325398